# How do I order tasks by "status id" and not "by label" in JIRA?

Tags: jira

Does anybody know how to order tasks by "status id" and not "by label" in JIRA?

Thanks.

Comment: Where in JIRA? In a API call or in a filter ?

Comment: JQL: order by status But why order by status id?

Comment: Because I don't need alphabetical sorting (as it is now), I need to order them by status ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can't search by status ID using Jira's search interface. Only navigable fields are searchable through the web interface using JQL, and statusID is not one of them...